# What is beats plugin for logstash?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I saw that logstash is used for sync data between a sql server and Elastic Search 5

In this [example](https://www.elastic.co/blog/logstash-jdbc-input-plugin) , it is shown that Logstash can use jdbc plugin for importing data from a database

But when I look at the available plugins, I notice one plugin  named [Beats](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-beats.html), 
it look like to also be used for importing data

I propapbly missanderstood , so is anybody acn explain me whatr the use of Beats plugin and hos is it used by logstash  please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logstash currently has [52 ways](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/input-plugins.html) of getting input.  As you've seen, [jdbc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html) and [beats](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-beats.html) are two.  Each of the inputs serves a different use case.  As described in the doc, jdbc is used to "ingest data in any database with a JDBC interface" while beats is used to "receive events from the Elastic Beats framework".

Depending on your needs, you would choose the appropriate input plugin.