# What are differences between Beats and jdbc plugin?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elasticsearch-plugin

I am a newbie in the ElasticSearch's wonderful world so please be indulgent.

I am thinking about an import and synchronisation strategy for a Microsoft sql data source and if I did not misunderstand, I can use the input plugins JDBC or Beats.

But I don't see what are the deeps differences between them,

what are their usefulness? When use one or other one?
What are their benefits and their drawbacks?

Thank you if you can help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is beats plugin for logstash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41467978/what-is-beats-plugin-for-logstash)

Comment: You have asked pretty much the same question before

Comment: it is another question, I learned that the 2 products could do the same thing, I now want to know when they are used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They serve different purposes. [Beats](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/libbeat/current/index.html) is another offering of the Elastic Stack, which is basically a platform for collecting and shipping data (logs, network packets, any kind of metrics, protocol data, etc) from the periphery of your architecture. Even though Beats also allows you to listen on the MySQL protocol and collect all kinds of metrics from your DB, it has nothing to do with loading data from your DB and load it into Elasticsearch. For that you can use the `jdbc` input plugin whose job is mainly to run a given query on regular time intervals and send each retrieved DB record as event through the Logstash pipeline to be processed further and sent to a variety of different outputs.